# Unused global option(s): [language=english]

Tags: documentclass-writing, xkeyval, options

This is a follow up question to [Options in custom class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417715/options-in-custom-class). It seems that I still did not understand how global options work. Consider the following code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sampleclass.cls}
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
    \ProvidesClass{sampleclass}

    %Providing key value syntax
    \RequirePackage{xkeyval}

    %Options
    \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
    \DeclareOptionX{language}{\PassOptionsToPackage{#1}{babel}}
    \ExecuteOptionsX{language=latin}

    \ProcessOptions\relax
    \ProcessOptionsX\relax

    %Parent class
    \LoadClass[
    ]{article}

    %Language support
    \RequirePackage{babel}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[language=english]{sampleclass}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

It prints the text in English - as it's supposed to - but gives the warning

```
Unused global option(s): [language=english].
```

If I comment out the line

```
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
```

the warning disappears. What is the correct way to use a `[language=english]` option for my custom class to pass the option `english` to `babel`? After some playing around I did not come to find out which parts of the above code actually lead to the warning so I will leave this not-so-minimal working example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `\DeclareOptionsX*` instead of `\DeclareOption*`, in order to process the user defined option (here with `xkeyval`)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sampleclass.cls}
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
    \ProvidesClass{sampleclass}

    %Providing key value syntax
    \RequirePackage{xkeyval}

    %Options
    \DeclareOptionX{language}{\PassOptionsToPackage{#1}{babel}}
    \DeclareOptionX*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
    \ExecuteOptionsX{language=latin}

    \ProcessOptions\relax
    \ProcessOptionsX\relax

    %Parent class


    \LoadClass{article}

    %Language support
    \RequirePackage{babel}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[language=ngerman]{sampleclass}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm very fast to upvote.+1 :-) Hi, dear friend.

Comment: Ah, and I guess if I want to include both xkeyvalue- and ordinary options in my document, I'll have to include both `\DeclareOptionX*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}` and `\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}` ?

Comment: @JohnDorian: No, `\DeclareOptionX*` should be sufficent, if I remember correctly.